# Reformat class "set" to class "str" and give readable output "txt" tab-delimited

Tags: python-3.x

hope somebody can help with the following issue:

I have two lists (.txt-files, tab-delimited) with entries of the following type:

Test.txt

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Effect
1   984971  984971  G   A   nonsynonymous
3   440760  440760  C   T   synonymous
4   515606  515606  C   T   frameshift
7   891100  891100  G   T   deletion
7   932053  932053  C   T   nonsynonymous
8   442614  442614  C   G   nonsynonymous
1   1177948 1177948 C   T   frameshift
11  824348  824348  A   C   frameshift
1   2126139 2126139 C   G   nonsynonymous
16  256154  256154  G   T   frameshift
```

Test2.txt

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Effect
1   984971  984971  G   A   nonsynonymous
3   440760  440760  C   T   synonymous
20  126224  126224  A   G   nonsynonymous
20  210225  210225  C   T   nonsynonymous
2   1499771 1499771 G   A   deletion
8   442614  442614  C   G   nonsynonymous
4   1107200 1107200 G   C   deletion
4   3132038 3132038 A   G   insertion
16  256154  256154  G   T   frameshift
4   3174738 3174738 G   T   insertion
7   1097111 1097111 G   A   nonsynonymous
```

As obvious, the following entries (lines) are common to both files:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Effect
1   984971  984971  G   A   nonsynonymous
3   440760  440760  C   T   synonymous
8   442614  442614  C   G   nonsynonymous
16  256154  256154  G   T   frameshift
```

To create a set with the common entries and give the output in class str I wrote the following code:

```
file_in1=open("c:\\python\\Test.txt","r")
file_in2=open("c:\\python\\Test2.txt","r")
file_out=open("c:\\python\\Common.txt","w")
out=str(set(file_in1).intersection(file_in2))
file_out.write(out)
```

Output gives:

```
{'1\t984971\t984971\tG\tA\tnonsynonymous SNV\n', '3\t440760\t440760\tC\tT\tsynonymous SNV\n', '16\t256154\t256154\tG\tT\tframeshift\n', '8\t442614\t442614\tC\tG\tnonsynonymous SNV\n', 'Chr\tStart\tEnd\tRef\tAlt\tEffect\n'}
```

My question is, how to format tabs (\t), newlines (\n) and braces ({}) to write output into a file purely .txt (tab-delimited). I looked up the python tutorial as well as the internet, but di not found a solution that works.

Comment: Not a full answer, but your problem is you are first creating a set, and then creating a string from that set.  This is where the curly braces from.  You will need to write more code, but basically you need to iterate through each element in the set and write that directly. (`for item in set`)

Comment: Hello Heikki, thank you for your suggestions. Iteration of the set helped! With using >>for item in file_out: print(file_out)<< I get the right output on the screen. The issue now is, how to write the set into a file (attribute .write neither works with object 'set', nor with object 'str' or 'list'). Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy - as far as you find the point: insert a <str("")> between <for item in file_out> and <file_out.write(item)> and writing into the file works well. Again thank you for the input, Heikki. :-)

Comment: Yaaaaay :) you should answer your own question with the code that worked so others with the same or similar problem may benefit